# How can I access the component of an instantiated object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so here's what's happening
I have this "Bullet" script with an "ApplyForce" method, attached to a Bullet prefab

```
public void ApplyForce (Vector2 direction)
{
    const float magnitude = 5f;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(magnitude * direction, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

And a "Ship" script that will instantiate a Bullet and try to access its "Bullet" component to then access the "ApplyForce" method to apply a force in the same direction the ship is facing

```
    // check for shooting input (left ctrl key) and fire
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>().ApplyForce(thrustDirection);
    }
```

Problem is, it doesn't work. It sends this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Ship.Update () (at Assets/scripts/Ship.cs:56)

I get that my problem is how to properly access the newly instantiated GameObject, but I couldn't find a proper way to do it. So here I am asking for your assistance.

I apologize for any newbie mistake that may anger you as I am fairly new to coding/programming and have next to 0 experience with this

Comment: The basic C# way would be `bullet.ApplyForce(thrustDirection);` And it hsould work the same way in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I found the problem: I am an absolute idiot! :D

I forgot to attach the Bullet script to the Bullet prefab

Answer (score 0):

which line is line 56? one common thing you can try is:

```
bullet.GetComponentInChildren<Bullet>().ApplyForce(thrustDirection);
```

if that still doesn't work and that is line 56, make sure that the 'thrustDirection' variable is not null.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work :/
And thrustDirection is not null, if it was the ship wouldn't move (it does)
Would you like it if I provided the entire two scripts?

Comment: And yes, this IS line 56

Comment: sure share entire scripts and a screen shot of your prefab and attached components